# Nest.js Tests Can't resolve dependencies of ReportingService (?, MasterMLRepository) - Sequelize is not available in the RootTestModule context

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, sequelize.js, nestjs

I'm writing tests in Nest.js. And I came across this error. I tried all the available solutions on the internet. Adding `Sequelize` to `imports`, `exports`, etc. But, none of them worked.

```
 Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ReportingService (?, MasterMLRepository). Please make sure that the argument Sequelize at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - Is RootTestModule a valid NestJS module?
    - If Sequelize is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
    - If Sequelize is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing Sequelize */ ]
      })
```

Please refer to the files below:

**reporting.controller.ts**

```
import { Controller, Get, Param } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PinoLogger } from 'nestjs-pino';
import { MasterML } from './reporting.model';
import { ReportingService } from './reporting.service';

@Controller()
export class ReportingController {
  constructor(
    private readonly reportingService: ReportingService,
    private readonly logger: PinoLogger,
  ) {
    this.logger.setContext(ReportingController.name);
  }

  @Get()
  async getMaterialIds(
    @Param('plantId') plantId: string,
  ): Promise<string[] | []> {
    try {
      return await this.reportingService.getMaterialIds(plantId);
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

**reporting.model.ts**

```
import { Column, Model, Table } from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table({ tableName: 'MASTER_ML' })
export class MasterML extends Model {
  @Column({ field: 'BATCH_ID' })
  batchId: string;

  @Column({ field: 'FEATURE_NAME' })
  featureName: string;

  @Column({ field: 'FEATURE_VALUE' })
  featureValue: string;

  @Column({ field: 'MATERIAL_ID' })
  materialId: string;

  @Column({ field: 'PLANT_ID' })
  plantId: string;

  @Column({ field: 'STAGE' })
  stage: string;

  @Column({ field: 'MANUFACTURE_DATE' })
  manufactureDate: Date;
}
```

**reporting.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { ReportingController } from './reporting.controller';
import { ReportingService } from './reporting.service';
import { MasterML } from './reporting.model';

@Module({
  imports: [SequelizeModule.forFeature([
    MasterML,
  ])],
  controllers: [ReportingController],
  providers: [ReportingService],
})
export class ReportingModule {}
```

**reporting.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { MasterML } from './reporting.model';

@Injectable()
export class ReportingService {
  materialIdAttributes: any[] = [
    [
      this.sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', this.sequelize.col('MATERIAL_ID')),
      'materialId',
    ],
  ];

  materialIdOrder: any[] = [[this.sequelize.literal("'materialId' ASC")]];

  constructor(
    public sequelize: Sequelize,
    @InjectModel(MasterML) private readonly masterMl: typeof MasterML,
  ) {}

  async getMaterialIds(
    plantId: string,
  ): Promise<string[] | []> {
    return this.masterMl.findAll({
      attributes: this.materialIdAttributes,
      where: { plantId },
      order: this.materialIdOrder,
    }).then((rows) => rows.map((row) => row.materialId));
  }
}
```

**reporting.service.spec.ts**

```
import { getModelToken } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { MasterML } from '../../../src/simply/reporting/reporting.model';
import { ReportingService } from '../../../src/simply/reporting/reporting.service';

const testMaterialIds: string[] = [
  'MTRL-1',
  'MTRL-2',
  'MTRL-3',
];

describe('ReportingService', () => {
  let service: ReportingService;
  let masterMlModel: typeof MasterML;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ReportingService,
        {
          provide: getModelToken(MasterML),
          useValue: {
            findAll: jest.fn(() => [testMaterialIds]),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();
    service = module.get(ReportingService);
    masterMlModel = module.get<typeof MasterML>(getModelToken(MasterML));
  });

  it('Service should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('getMaterialIds - should be defined', async () => {
    expect(await service.getMaterialIds('PLNT1')).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should get the getMaterialIds', async () => {
    expect(await service.getMaterialIds('PLNT1')).toEqual([testMaterialIds]);
    const findAllSpy = jest.spyOn(masterMlModel, 'findAll');
    expect(findAllSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**simply.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { PlantModule } from './plant/plant.module';
import { Plant } from './plant/plant.model';
import { ProductModule } from './product/product.module';
import { ProcessModule } from './process/process.module';
import { ReportingModule } from './reporting/reporting.module';
import { Product } from './product/product.model';
import { Process } from './process/process.model';
import { MasterML } from './reporting/reporting.model';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/plants',
    module: PlantModule,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/:plantId/products',
        module: ProductModule,
        children: [
          {
            path: '/:productId/processes',
            module: ProcessModule,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: '/:plantId/reporting',
        children: [
          {
            path: '/materialids',
            module: ReportingModule,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
@Module({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.register(routes),
    PlantModule,
    ProductModule,
    ProcessModule,
    ReportingModule,
  ],
})
export class SimplyModule {
  constructor(public sequelize: Sequelize) {
    this.sequelize.addModels([
      Plant,
      Product,
      Process,
      MasterML,
    ]);
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { LoggerModule, Params } from 'nestjs-pino';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TerminusModule } from '@nestjs/terminus';
import { SequelizeModuleOptions, SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import {
  apiConfig, logConfig, sequelizeConfig,
} from './config';

import JoiSchema from './config/schema/validation.schema';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { TerminusController } from './terminus/terminus.controller';
import { SimplyModule } from './simply/simply.module';

const imports = [
  TerminusModule,
  ConfigModule.forRoot({
    validationSchema: JoiSchema,
    validationOptions: {
      allowUnknown: true,
      abortEarly: false,
    },
    isGlobal: true,
    envFilePath: process.env.NODE_ENV ? `env/.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` : 'env/.env.local',
    load: [
      apiConfig,
      logConfig,
      sequelizeConfig,
    ],
  }),

  LoggerModule.forRootAsync({
    useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => configService.get<Params>('log'),
    inject: [ConfigService],
  }),
  SequelizeModule.forRootAsync({
    useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) =>
      configService.get<SequelizeModuleOptions>('sequelize'),
    inject: [ConfigService],
  }),
  AuthModule,
  SimplyModule,
];

@Module({
  imports,
  controllers: [TerminusController],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You are missing Sequalize in providers array inside `createTestingModule`

Comment: @MariuszBartnik I have tried it. It did not work.

Comment: Can you show how you added `Sequelize` to the providers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mocked Sequelize and its functions -

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ProcessReportingService,
        {
          provide: Sequelize,
          useValue: {
            fn: jest.fn,
            col: jest.fn,
            literal: jest.fn,
            where: jest.fn,
          },
        },
        {
          provide: getModelToken(MasterML),
          useValue: {
            findAll: jest.fn(() => new Promise((resolve) => {
              resolve(testRawMaterialIds);
            })),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: getModelToken(Int2Calculations),
          useValue: {
            findAll: jest.fn(() => new Promise((resolve) => {
              resolve(testInt2CalculationsRows);
            })),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();
    service = module.get(ProcessReportingService);
    masterMlModel = module.get<typeof MasterML>(getModelToken(MasterML));
    int2CalculationsModel = module.get<typeof Int2Calculations>(getModelToken(Int2Calculations));
  });
```